# Accessing ServiceNow without API access?

Tags: web-scraping, servicenow

My place of work doesn't allow anyone but the ServiceNow support group to have API access.  I do most of our work in ServiceNow and the web interface is slow and cumbersome, especially if you have to create multiple things at a time, i.e. in my case Change Requests.  Has anyone had any luck using any non-API AND non-third-party tools to access ServiceNow?

I have tried a using bash, python and PowerShell, even just to get info but no luck.  I have also looked at the possibility of using HTTP GET/POST but haven't found anything that looks like it would work using just a "user" role.

I have thought about trying to webscrape but my options are very limited due to the Draconian rules is place.  Thus using a Chrome extension is out and trying to get perl or python modules installed(via Cygwin) is problematic.

Comment: If not having that access prevents you from doing your work efficiently, talk to your manager. Trying to bypass the rules is more likely to get you fired than promoted.

Comment: Mat - Um, yeh.  I've done that several times and even my manager can't get the access pushed through.  As for as the "more likely  to get you fired than promoted" comment - really?  I am trying to do my current job more efficiently if not completely automate it without added costs.  If they want to fire me for that then I need fired(or quit) and find a company that wants such things.

Answer (score 0):

One option should be to create an Inbound email action in order to create Change Request just sending email to the distro that your instance manages.

Take a look:
[Inbound email actions](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-servicenow-platform/page/administer/notification/concept/c_InboundEmailActions.html)